# Add a trailing slash at the end of each url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have a little problem here. I need to add a trailing slash at the end of each url in the site I'm working on. I defined all the links inside the site to have a trailing slash like so:

```
<a href="/register/">Register</a>
```

While this works fine there's still one tiny issue: it's with the generated urls that come from calling RedirectToAction(). For example:

```
return RedirectToAction("Register", "Users");
```

Will cause the url to change to /register with no trailing slash. I modified my routing system as so:

```
  routes.MapRoute("register",
                        "register/",
                        new {controller = "Users", action = "Register"}
            );
```

Still the required trailing slash doesn't get added automatically! 
I looked up this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077206/adding-a-trailing-slash-for-specific-redirection-rules) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx) but these are totally different as I'm not using any url rewriting libraries, i'm just using asp.net mvc routing system. 
So what do you say guys?

Comment: For anyone interested on how to do this for ASP.NET Core use `services.Configure<RouteOptions>(routeOptions => {         routeOptions.AppendTrailingSlash = true;};` where `services` is an `IServiceCollection`

Comment: In order to access `RouteOptions` be sure to `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The RouteCollection Class now has a AppendTrailingSlash boolean which you can set to true for this behavior.

Comment: `AppendTrailingSlash`does not rewrite routes.

Answer (score 21):

You can create a new Route which overrides the `GetVirtualPath` method. In this method you add a trailing slash to the `VirtualPath`. Like this:

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
     VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

     if (path != null)
         path.VirtualPath = path.VirtualPath + "/";
     return path;
}
```

For brevity I posted the [whole example on CodePaste.net](http://codepaste.net/exq9mg)

Now all you have to do is register the routes with `routes.MapRouteTrailingSlash()` instead of `routes.MapRoute()`.

```
routes.MapRouteTrailingSlash("register",
                             "register",
                             new {controller = "Users", action = "Register"}
);
```

The route will then add a slash to the path when the `GetVirtualPath()` is called. Which `RedirectToAction()` will do.

**Update:** Because the CodePaste link is down, here is the full code:

```
public class TrailingSlashRoute : Route {
    public TrailingSlashRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, routeHandler) {}

    public TrailingSlashRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, routeHandler) {}

    public TrailingSlashRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints,
                          IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints, routeHandler) {}

    public TrailingSlashRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints,
                          RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler) {}

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values) {
        VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

        if (path != null)
            path.VirtualPath = path.VirtualPath + "/";
        return path;
    }
}

public static class RouteCollectionExtensions {
    public static void MapRouteTrailingSlash(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults) {
        routes.MapRouteTrailingSlash(name, url, defaults, null);
    }

    public static void MapRouteTrailingSlash(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults,
                                         object constraints) {
        if (routes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");

        if (url == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");

        var route = new TrailingSlashRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
                    {
                        Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
                        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints)
                    };

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            routes.Add(route);
        else
            routes.Add(name, route);
    }
}
```

Comment: CodePaste.net link is expired. Any chance of reposting?

Comment: I would really like to see the whole example code that you mention. Unfortunately your link is broken :( Any chance you could provide an alternative link so I can see your example code please?

Comment: Added the code to the post. Hope that helps! Sorry about the dead link.

Comment: thank you so much for this.  saved me from rewriting a TON of forms!

Comment: -1 This doesn't work when the url contains a querystring. The slash will get placed after the querystring.

Comment: How to specify namespace?

Answer (score 5):

Nice clean solution, codingbug!!

Only problem I ran into was double trailing slashes for the home page in MVC3.

Razor example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

Linked to:
http://mysite.com//

To fix this I tweaked the GetVirtualPath override:

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{       
    VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);       

    if (path != null && path.VirtualPath != "")       
        path.VirtualPath = path.VirtualPath + "/";       
    return path;       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The above solution by codingbug is very nice. I needed something very similar, but only for my root URL. I know there are possible problems with this, but here is what I did. It seems to work just fine in all of my environments. I think it works too, because it is only our Home page when they first come and do not have the training slash. That is the one case I was trying to avoid. If that is what you want to avoid, this will work for you.

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      if (!Request.RawUrl.Contains("Index") && !Request.RawUrl.EndsWith("/"))
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "" });
```

If it turns out I need more than this. I will probably use code that codingbug provided. Until then, I like to keep it simple.

Note: I am counting on Home\Index to be removed from the URL by the routing engine.

Answer (score 1):

I found a far easier solution than the most upvoted answer:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/", <-- trailing slash here
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This will act as trailing slash "/" in all the cases.

Comment: No, it won't. If do it this way and then you generate url using RouteUrl("{name of a route"}, new RouteValueDictionary({parameters})), the trailing slash gets cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some MVC Controller code of how I implement it in a very simple get.

```
public ActionResult Orders()
{
    if (!Request.Path.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        return RedirectPermanent(Request.Url.ToString() + "/");
    }
    return View();
}
```