# How do I put a slash on the end of an ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a trailing slash at the end of each url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385265/add-a-trailing-slash-at-the-end-of-each-url)

I need to append a forward slash on the end of the ActionLink.  How would I do that?  This is for SEO purposes.

```
@Html.ActionLink("About Us","Index","About")
```

**From this:**
http://www.somesite.com/About

**To this:**
http://www.somesite.com/About/

Comment: here's a post that likely will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385265/add-a-trailing-slash-at-the-end-of-each-url

Comment: This is clearly not an exact duplicate, at all. The OP asked for adding a trailing slash to a single ActionLink, not EVERY URL on the site, like the other question.

Comment: OP: In the `Index` case, use `@Html.ActionLink("Text", "/", "Controller")` otherwise use `@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action/", "Controller")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the URL rewrite module to enforce your SEO requirements throughout the site, without the need to write specific route functionality. This is managed from your web.config...

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Remove trailing slash" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*[^/])/$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="POST" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```